# "Thank you in each case" usage

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests, formality, phrase-usage, gratitude

I was wondering is the phrase "Thank you in each case" appropriate to say at the end of question asking someone for some help, in formal or informal situations. I very often use it, and was thinking it was okay, but now it has occured me it may look "cold" to people (informally) or not so professional.. Can someone tell me what do English language experts think about that phrase, and what should be better used instead expressing gratitude? (i'm not native in English)

Thank you very much for consideration.

Comment: *Is "Thank you in each case" an appropriate thing to say at the end of a question asking someone for some help, in formal or informal situations.* No. You thank someone **after** they have done something. Some people find "Thank you in advance" and such phrases objectionable (I'm one of them...)

Comment: @Greybeard What then could be used? "Thank you for consideration" or "Thank you very much", "Thank you for your time"?:)

Comment: "I would appreciate any help." Suppose it's a question here, when you say "thanks in advance" and the question gets closed? Then it looks silly (closed questions can still be viewed by many).